# How can i add a back button to my nav bar in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, routes, back

I am looking for some example or help on how i can add a back button to my reactjs application ... The below throws this error when i click on Go Back on my nav bar

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css'

export default class Navbar extends Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  goBack = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            My App
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="https://app.com">
              Home
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using React Router ? If no you could use `window.history.back()` see the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_his_back.asp).

Comment: yeap i am using React Router

Answer (score 1):

If using react-router-dom  your can use  `this.props.history.goBack()` method which take you back one step. to learn more on methods you can use with [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

Answer (score 0):

You ca use `this.props.history.goBack`

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  goBack = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            My App
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="https://app.com">
              Home
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem onClick={this.goBack} />
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry about this (i am still learning) but how would i "plug" that in to my navbar code

Comment: I am seeing this error now .... TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined ..... i will keep digging

Comment: don't forget to `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom`